# Reply email using php-ews

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, email, php-ews

I am using php-ews for reading the exchange mailbox. However, i would like to pick an e-mail from the inbox and reply to that e-mail, with the email history and send the response. Below is the code that i am using to get the specific email from the Inbox.

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($account_array['server'], $account_array['username'], $account_array['password'], ExchangeWebServices::VERSION_2010_SP1);
$message_id = 'AAMkADU3ZDdmZmY3LWI3OGMtNDRmMy1hYTdlLTBlZjkwOGE3NTU5MwBGAAAAAADkJRKCdlaES7sRqf3veO/UBwCgoREk6zyqQqi6KC/gJMy0AAAAvGoCAACgoREk6zyqQqi6KC/gJMy0AAAAvGpQAAA=';
$change_id = 'CQAAABYAAACgoREk6zyqQqi6KC/gJMy0AAAAvMEZ';

$request = new EWSType_GetItemType();
$request -> ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$request -> ItemShape -> BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::ALL_PROPERTIES;

$request -> ItemShape -> BodyType = EWSType_BodyTypeResponseType::HTML;

$body_property = new EWSType_PathToUnindexedFieldType();
$body_property -> FieldURI = 'item:Body';
$request -> ItemShape -> AdditionalProperties = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfPathsToElementType();
$request -> ItemShape -> AdditionalProperties -> FieldURI = array($body_property);

$request -> ItemIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseItemIdsType();
$request -> ItemIds -> ItemId = array();

$message_item = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
$message_item -> Id = trim($message_id);
$request -> ItemIds -> ItemId[] = $message_item;

$response = $ews -> GetItem($request);
//print '<pre>' . print_r($response, true) . '</pre><hr/>';
$message = $response -> ResponseMessages -> GetItemResponseMessage -> Items -> Message;

print '<pre>' . print_r($message, true) . '</pre><hr/>';
```

Now that i have got the message to reply to, how do i take this further and draft a response message and create a Reply Item for this email.

I have searched Google for this, but no luck.

Drilling into the php-ews classes for hours, i took a look at EWSType_ReplyAllToItemType, EWSType_PostReplyItemType, EWSType_PostReplyItemBaseType, etc. but unable to understand how to use these codes.

Please help guys! any helps would be greatly appreciated.

I am sure that any response to this post would be helpful since there are no forums talking 
about this. :)

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replying to an email using php exchange web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318780/replying-to-an-email-using-php-exchange-web-services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Finally found an answer on how to ReplyTo an E-mail using PHP-EWS.**

Firstly, we need to modify EWSType/MessageType.php and add the below line at the end of the class just before closing of the class:

```
public $NewBodyContent;
```

and the reply function goes as:

```
Public function replyToMessage($id,$changeKey)
    {
        $ews = new ExchangeWebServices($this->server_url, $this->username, $this->password, ExchangeWebServices::VERSION_2010_SP1);

        //$msg = new EWSType_ReplyAllToItemType();
        $msg = new EWSType_MessageType();

//In Case you need to add anyone in CC
        $cc = new EWSType_ArrayOfRecipientsType();
        $cc->Mailbox = new EWSType_EmailAddressType();
        $cc->Mailbox->EmailAddress = 'emailaddresshere';
        $cc->Mailbox->Name = 'displaynamehere';
        $msg->CcRecipients = $cc;

        $msg->ReferenceItemId = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
        $msg->ReferenceItemId->Id = $id;
        $msg->ReferenceItemId->ChangeKey = $changeKey;

        $msg->NewBodyContent = new EWSType_BodyType();
        $msg->NewBodyContent->BodyType = 'HTML';
        $msg->NewBodyContent->_ = 'HTML Content Goes Here';

        $msgRequest = new EWSType_CreateItemType();
        $msgRequest->Items = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfAllItemsType();
        $msgRequest->Items->ReplyAllToItem = $msg;
        $msgRequest->MessageDisposition = 'SendAndSaveCopy';
        $msgRequest->MessageDispositionSpecified = TRUE;

        $response = $ews->CreateItem($msgRequest);

        return $response->ResponseMessages->CreateItemResponseMessage->ResponseCode;

    }
```

This will send a Reply to the specified ID and ChangeKey

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply send a new email to the reply address of the email you want to reply to?

https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/wiki/Email:-Send-Email

Set the subject to `Re: <subject of previous message>`

And then simply include the body of the original email underneath the body of the response?

Comment: hey bencoder, thank you for your prompt response. Is there any other way we can do it... i do not want to include the body of the previous e-mail manually!

Comment: I don't know if there's another way as I don't know php-ews, this was just an idea/suggestion to help you move forward. I doubt there's any specific functionality to include the previous body automatically though. That wouldn't really make sense since this would be a client-dependent feature.